# Wordpress Error occurred: 404 - not found

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting, web-hosting, transfer

I transfer my wordpress site to the other domain server but when my wordpress website is online I can only see my home page but if i will go to other page link like contact us the error will occurred and it says Error occurred: 404 - not found. anyone knows how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess file on the new server? Just in case, go to the Dashboard and re-set your permalink options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to dashboard and change the permalink of your site to default. And recheck your site. If it works it will be great and if it doesn't work check your database by downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

Links of your site pages and post are not correctly modified to new server. you need to get .xml file from old server then change links manually using notepad or some other editor, then import that file with changes links to new server. Also you need to set permalinks for site as it was for old site.

Comment: Great, if the issue is resolved. You can mark the answer as right.